# How do I animate opacity change inside a waypoint function based on scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I am working on a project, here: https://github.com/erinreiss/spaceship1/tree/ministory1

And I am looking to make a div#landing to go from opacity:1 to opacity:0 within 200 pixels of scrolling, based on scroll position. I was able to do it successfully like this:

```
var target = $('#landing');
var targetHeight = 200;
 $(document).scroll(function(e){
     var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
     if(scrollPercent >= 0){
         target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
     }
});
```

Now, I want to use waypoints to trigger this same effect but at a different time. I want instead of it firing as the div#landing moves out of the viewport, it instead fires as a defined Waypoint (in this case, a different div#intro1) is scrolled past.

This is my attempt:

```
var target = $('#landing');
var targetHeight = 200;
var intro1 = $('#intro1').waypoint(function (direction) {
    console.log('bam!');
    $(document).scroll(function(e){
      var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
        if(scrollPercent >= 0){
            target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
        }
    })
}, {offset: 200});
```

The waypoint fires, but (alas) the scrolling opacity changer does not work...

Any advice? Thank you!!

ps - The other thread with this question is answered with code no longer available :(

[How do I animate on scroll inside a waypoint function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106677/how-do-i-animate-on-scroll-inside-a-waypoint-function)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve this problem, but I did hack something together close to what I wanted... It allows me to use the scroll position of an overflow element to trigger and define the level of opacity on another element.

See solution here:
https://github.com/erinreiss/spaceship1/tree/ministory1

```
var target = $('#intro1inner');
$('#intro1inner').scroll(function(){
      //define a variable that will be how much the target has scrolled from its original position
      var changeA = target.scrollTop()
      console.log('changeA:' + changeA)
    // I want my change in opacity (from 0-1 to take place over 250px)
      var scrollPercent = changeA / 250;
      console.log('scrollPercent:' + scrollPercent)
    });
```